# DETACH database before releasing SAVEPOINT?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm using a C# library that internally uses a SQLite database. This library uses a SAVEPOINT so changes made to the database can be later committed or discarded, the same way most file editors work. Changes are committed to the database by calling the `SaveChanges` function, which calls `RELEASE SAVEPOINT...` behind the scenes.

I want to be able to export one of the tables in the database into a new SQLite database while changes are still pending, and include the pending changes. I don't want to have to commit the changes just to be able to export the table. Since I have access to the source database `SqliteConnection`, I could query the source table to get a `DbDataReader` and then loop through the results while inserting the data into the target database.

But it should be possible to make this faster by doing something like this:

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'Target.db' AS `target`;
CREATE TABLE `target`.`targetTable` AS SELECT * FROM `sourceTable`;
DETACH DATABASE `target`;
```

The problem is that after creating my `targetTable`, the target database remains locked until I commit the changes in the source database. This causes the `DETACH DATABASE` line to throw *"The process cannot access the file ..."*, and prevent me from accessing the target database.

Is there any way to do a kind of table dump other than having to loop through the results of a query?